# Moto G 2nd Gen - looping on optimizing apps

Tags: boot-loop, boot, motorola-moto-g

I believe I have a Moto G 2nd Gen (may be 1st or 3rd, not really sure). When I turn it on, it displays the Motorola splash screen animation and then displays "Optimizing app 1 of 150", then 2 of 150, etc. until 150 of 150. Then it restarts the process from 1 of 150 again forever. I have run it overnight and it still keeps repeating.

I have all my data backed up already, so I wanted to try an external factory reset. However, following the instructions (pressing power button and volume down, selecting "Factory") only led me to a picture of a green robot with an open chest plate with the caption "No command." This forced me to restart and led me nowhere.

When I tried to boot in recovery mode, the white notification light began blinking slowly, but nothing really happened.

What should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get to the "Dead Andy" screen and it times out saying "No Command" hold POWER and tap VOL UP and release quickly. It should open the stock Recovery menu where you will see the various update and reset options.

I would first try to Wipe the cache partition and reboot and see if that clears the issue. If the problem persists, go back to the stock recovery menu and perform a factory reset.